# Magento 2.2 Release note

Tags: magento2.2

I want to know what is meaning of this?

Magento no longer locks the category_product_entity table. Unlocking this table reduces the potential of lock-related timeouts that can occur when indexing and checkout operations run in parallel. Previously, Magento locked the category_product_entity table.

is it related to category product reindex? what related to this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes
When you face indexing lock issue you can unlock by using below command

```
php bin/magento indexer:reset
```

This command just reset all indexing so indexing lock issue resolve and you can re-run

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

If you want to reset particular index (e.g. catalogsearch_fulltext), you can run the following command:

```
php bin/magento indexer:reset catalogsearch_fulltext
```

Comment: If there is a error occurs while re indexing category_product_entity it will not skipped?

Comment: it will skip and you need to reindex again